# ggplot2: One legend with both shapes and colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe, where I want to visualize plot the data using both shape, alpha and colour.
I have shown the dataframe below. I have created the Type and Shapetype column, to have something to specify for colour and shape. This is working quite well - but I need to edit the legend, and I cannot figure out a way to do that.
I have a legend that shows the shapes.

[image: Shapes]

But I need the colours for MS and MT to show as the last two rows in the legend as well.

[image: Colours]

Here's the data:

```
Locus;Island;AR;Type;Shapetype
MS1;ST;4,6315;MS;NA
MS1;FG;3,9689;MS;NA
MS1;SN;3;MS;NA
MS2;ST;2;MS;NA
MS2;FG;2;MS;NA
MS2;SN;2;MS;NA
MS3;ST;7,5199;MS;NA
MS3;FG;5,5868;MS;NA
MS3;SN;3;MS;NA
MS4;ST;2,9947;MS;NA
MS4;FG;3;MS;NA
MS4;SN;2;MS;NA
MS5;ST;9,0726;MS;NA
MS5;FG;5,6759;MS;NA
MS5;SN;2,963;MS;NA
MS6;ST;6,5779;MS;NA
MS6;FG;5,6842;MS;NA
MS6;SN;2;MS;NA
MS7;ST;2;MS;NA
MS7;FG;1;MS;NA
MS7;SN;1;MS;NA
MS8;ST;3,97;MS;NA
MS8;FG;2,9032;MS;NA
MS8;SN;1;MS;NA
MS9;ST;2;MS;NA
MS9;FG;1,9977;MS;NA
MS9;SN;2;MS;NA
MS10;ST;3,9733;MS;NA
MS10;FG;3,9971;MS;NA
MS10;SN;2;MS;NA
MS11;ST;7,4172;MS;NA
MS11;FG;5,6471;MS;NA
MS11;SN;3;MS;NA
MS12;ST;2;MS;NA
MS12;FG;2;MS;NA
MS12;SN;2;MS;NA
MS13;ST;5,6135;MS;NA
MS13;FG;3;MS;NA
MS13;SN;2;MS;NA
MT;ST;12;MT;NA
MT;FG;3;MT;NA
MT;SN;2;MT;NA
TLR1LA;ST;3,68;TLR;TLR1LA
TLR1LA;FG;4,4;TLR;TLR1LA
TLR1LA;SN;1;TLR;TLR1LA
TLR1LB;ST;3,99;TLR;TLR1LB
TLR1LB;FG;5;TLR;TLR1LB
TLR1LB;SN;1;TLR;TLR1LB
TLR2A;ST;4,9;TLR;TLR2A
TLR2A;FG;5;TLR;TLR2A
TLR2A;SN;2;TLR;TLR2A
TLR2B;ST;5,64;TLR;TLR2B
TLR2B;FG;4;TLR;TLR2B
TLR2B;SN;3;TLR;TLR2B
TLR3;ST;1;TLR;TLR3
TLR3;FG;3;TLR;TLR3
TLR3;SN;3;TLR;TLR3
TLR4;ST;1;TLR;TLR4
TLR4;FG;2,89;TLR;TLR4
TLR4;SN;2;TLR;TLR4
TLR5;ST;2,9;TLR;TLR5
TLR5;FG;2;TLR;TLR5
TLR5;SN;2;TLR;TLR5
TLR21;ST;2,91;TLR;TLR21
TLR21;FG;1;TLR;TLR21
TLR21;SN;1;TLR;TLR21
```

With this, I have created a plot that is very close to what I want:

```
ggplot(comb, aes(Island, AR, group = Locus, colour = (factor(Type)))) + geom_line(aes(colour = factor(Type), alpha = factor(Type), size = factor(Type))) + scale_alpha_manual(values = c("MS"=0.2, "MT"=0.2, "TLR" = 1)) + scale_size_manual(values = c("MS"=0.5, "MT"=0.5, "TLR" = 0.3)) + xlab("Island") + ylab("Allelic Richness") + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Santiago", "Fogo", "Sao Nicolau"), limits = c("ST", "FG", "SN")) + geom_point(aes(shape = (factor(Shapetype)))) + scale_shape_manual(values = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), breaks=c("TLR1LA","TLR1LB","TLR2A","TLR2B","TLR3","TLR4","TLR5","TLR21", "MS", "MT")) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("Red","Blue","Black"), breaks=c("TLR1LA","TLR1LB","TLR2A","TLR2B","TLR3","TLR4","TLR5","TLR21", "MS", "MT")) + theme_bw()
```

However, I now have three legends, and I only want a single (as explained above).
So firstly, the alpha-legend should be removed - I have tried with `guide=FALSE` and with `+ guides(alpha=FALSE)`, but I cannot get them to work.
Second, I need a legend that is the shape legend combined with two extra rows. One for the colour for MS and one for the colour of MT. (Preferably with no dot in the middle, just a coloured line).
I have tried to get this by changing my `scale_shape_manual` and `scale_colour_manual`, but I have had no luck. I have also tried making identical labels to remove a legend, but I have had no luck with this either.

Comment: This is non-standard (read not recommended) and thus not easy in ggplot2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Roland.
I would of course prefer to do it in ggplot2, as I have done this plot as well as all my other plots in this package for the thesis I am doing.
I guess your answer leaves me with two questions:
1) Is it actually possible to do in ggplot2 - and how?
2) What alternatives (to ggplot2 or to the legend issue in ggplot2) are there?

Comment: It is possible. I vaguely remember an answer on SO showing how, but I don't have time to search. However, you should not do this. It's not a good idea to mix legends like this.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with your statement "It's not a good idea to mix legends like this". Could you maybe elaborate a bit? Do you mean in regards to ggplot in particular or just in general? For my data in particular, it makes perfect sense to present it with a single legend showing both shapes and the colours.

Comment: It's not good design of a plot.